# why there is no vendor.js in chunks during development phase in angular 17

Tags: angular, angular17

I am exploring Angular 17 and I am comparing it with Angular 16 and I noticed that there in no vendor.js

[image]

I tried to modify angular.json by adding "vendorChunk": true in angular 17 but I think they have removed that
[image]

Can someone explain why there is no vendor.js in angular 17 and it works under the hood

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on the [CLI repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25283):

> Overall, vendor chunking should have only been used for development
> purposes. This only existed in the Webpack builder to workaround
> rebuild time issues that Webpack has. While indeed Esbuild does
> generate more chunks, this does not necessary mean they are all
> initial, and in the majority of cases this is done to return initial
> size which should improve CWV as Webpack's module concatenation causes
> a lot of unneeded code to be put in the initial chunk.